# JS and jQuery, global object gets empty when function is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, scope, javascript-objects

I have a problem with an object **dict**. When json datas are received, program calls **LoadDict()** function, where dict object gets filled with new data from server. I used FireBug to make sure that dict has all new elements with correct information, but when function is finished, **dict** gets empty again like it was before ajax request. This code executes in the global scope:

```
var dict = new Dictionary();
function LoadDict(words) {
    for (var i in words) {
        var word = new Word();
        word.word = words[i].Word;
        word.transcript = words[i].Transcript;
        word.frequency = words[i].Frequency;
        word.meanings = words[i].Meanings;
        word.examples = words[i].Examples;
        word.imgLinks = words[i].ImgLinks;
        dict.Add(word);
    }
}
$.getJSON("getall").done(LoadDict);
dict.PrintDictionary);
```

And this is some code of my Dictionary class

```
function Dictionary() {
    this.collection = new Array();
    this.count = 0;
    this.sorted = false;
}

Dictionary.prototype.Add = function(word) {
    if (word instanceof Word) {
        word.id = this.count;
        this.collection[this.count] = word;
        this.count++;
        this.sorted = false;
    }
}
Dictionary.prototype.PrintDictionary = function() { 
    function WordToString(word) {
        var line = "<strong>" + word.word + "</strong> [" + word.transcript + "] - " + word.meanings[0];
        for (var j = 1; j < word.meanings.length; j++) {
            line += ", " + word.meanings[j];
        }
        return line;
    }
    var result = "<ol>"
    for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++)
        result += "<li>" + WordToString(this.collection[i]) + "</li>";
    result += "</ol>"
    document.write(result);
}
```

Declaration of Dictionary class goes before creating dict object.
Help, please!

Comment: may be you cantry it sync call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `$.getJSON` is async.

This means that the `dict.PrintDictionary();` line gets executed **before** the result is returned from the `getJSON` call

Answer (score 1):

A timing problem.

In your code, `PrintDictionary` function have excuted before ajax call is complete.